# count groupings of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have a table of tickets to multiple dates of shows shows. basically, it looks like this...

```
+----+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| ID | ticket_holder | ticket_buyer | show_date |
+----+---------------+--------------+-----------+
```

ticket_holder and ticket_buyer are both user ids

If I wanted to count the total number of tickets that one ticket holder has, I could group by that holder and count the rows, but I want more stats than that.

I want to know a user's total bought tickets, how many they hold and how many shows they've bought tickets for.

```
+------+---------+--------+-------+
| USER | HOLDING | BOUGHT | DATES |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
| 1    | 12      | 24     | 7     |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
| 2    | 3       | 4      | 2     |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
| 3    | 1       | 2      | 1     |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
```

is it possible to put all this in a query, or do i need to do php stuff to make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in multiple queries. You can't group by *either* `ticket_holder` or `ticket_buyer` like you want, in a single query. If you try `GROUP BY ticket_holder, ticket_buyer` then it will group by *both* columns, which is not what you want.

```
SELECT ticket_holder, COUNT(*) AS tickets_held
FROM `a table of tickets` GROUP BY ticket_holder;

SELECT ticket_buyer, COUNT(*) as tickets_bought 
FROM `a table of tickets` GROUP BY ticket_buyer;

SELECT ticket_buyer, COUNT(DISTINCT show_date) AS shows_bought
FROM `a table of tickets` GROUP BY ticket_buyer;
```

Not every task has to be accomplished in a single query! It's part of the design of SQL that it should be used by some application language, and you're expected to handle formatting and display in the application.